# How to separate Development and Production sidekiq workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I am running sidekiq on a production rails server, and some of its queues workers end up in my development sidekiq instance and, therefore, causes a bunch of errors. The same thing happens with my development sidekiq instance. When I'm in the development version of the application and I click something that kicks off a sidekiq worker, it sometimes tries to run it in the production sidekiq instance and the production database doesn't have the same information.

Is there a proper way to separate these queued jobs so that they only run in the instance which they are initiated?

Answer (score 3):

Sidekiq uses Redis to store enqueued jobs. By default, all sidekiq instances will use the default Redis database. You can change this by creating an initializer in *config/initializers/sidekiq.rb*

```
if Rails.env == :production 
  redis_host = '127.0.0.1'
  redis_port = 6379
  redis_db = 1
else
  redis_host = '127.0.0.1'
  redis_port = 6379
  redis_db = 2
end

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: "redis://#{redis_host}:#{redis_port}/#{redis_db}" }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: "redis://#{redis_host}:#{redis_port}/#{redis_db}" }  
end
```

And change `redis_host`, `redis_port` and `redis_db` with appropriate values. This way each environment will use a separate Redis database. Also don't forget to pass appropriate environment when starting a sidekiq instance with something like:

```
bundle exec sidekiq -e production
```

Comment: I may be a little confused here. Do I really need to set up a separate redis database or can I just simply use different queues? Also, are workers aware of which queue they are being run in based on what called it? Reason I ask is because I have scheduled workers that calls Worker1. Worker1 calls Worker2, and I need to make sure Worker2 is called and runs in the same queue as Worker1.